# existence of nonlinear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

do we have any transformation in form of  $ T : R^2 \longrightarrow R $ that holds
for each vector like $v$ in $ xy $ plane and any real constant like $ r$  this equality $$ T(rv) = rT(v) $$
but it isn't a linear transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take, for instance,$$T(x,y)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }y=0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$